# Value comparison

Tags: python, python-2.7, compare, python-2.x

I would like to give a label according to numeric value comparison. However, labels are not true at the end.

Is there anybody who could help me?

```
labels = []
for x,y in zip(multiply_nonspam_test, multiply_spam_test):
    if x > y:
        label = 0
        labels.append(label)
    elif x == y:
        label = 2
        labels.append(label)
    elif x < y:
        label = 1
        labels.append(label)

print labels

multiply_nonspam_test: [-0.0, -5.5014525551182665, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -20.347159201740993, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -5.403260528939053, -0.0, -0.0, -9.239122173401634, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0]

multiply_spam_test: [-0.0, -4.564151631270644, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -13.658061604139832, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -5.322256708105361]
```

label result(not true):

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1..]
```

Comment: Works for me. Just copy and pasting your code gives me: print labels [2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1] It's hard to tell exactly what the issue is just from looking at your results. Possibly try each of the labelling checks independently to break down the problem.

Comment: Beware of small errors when comparing floats for equality. You may want to implement a "roughly-equals" comparison that enforces equality for only a certain number of digits.

Comment: Your code works fine.  You must have used different lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program actually works fine. Somehow you must have given it wrong lists. I created a little function for you to display this.

```
# Your original lists
list1 = [-0.0, -5.5014525551182665, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -20.347159201740993, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -5.403260528939053, -0.0, -0.0, -9.239122173401634, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0]
list2 = [-0.0, -4.564151631270644, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -13.658061604139832, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -5.322256708105361]


def compare_lists(list1, list2):
    labels = []
    for x, y in zip(list1, list2):
        if x > y:
            label = 0
            labels.append(label)
        elif x == y:
            label = 2
            labels.append(label)
        elif x < y:
            label = 1
            labels.append(label)

    return labels

# Output [2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1]
print compare_lists(list1, list2)
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried this using Python 3.5.1 on Mac OSX:

```
multiply_nonspam_test = [-0.0, -5.5014525551182665, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -20.347159201740993, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -5.403260528939053, -0.0, -0.0, -9.239122173401634, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0]
multiply_spam_test = [-0.0, -4.564151631270644, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -13.658061604139832, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -5.322256708105361]

labels = []
for x,y in zip(multiply_nonspam_test, multiply_spam_test):
    if x > y:
        labels.append(0)
    elif x == y:
        labels.append(2)
    elif x < y:
        labels.append(1)

print(labels)
```

And got this result:

```
[2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1]
```